# Electronic Circuit Simulator API/Libraries

Tags: programming, simulation, library

Are there any Electronic circuit simulator libraries/API that I can use to construct virtual circuit simulators like SPICE etc? My main research area is not Electronic simulation since I'm a Computer science undergrad so I have to give priority to Software Engineering aspects.

thanks

Comment: Your main research area is "no thanks"???

Comment: sorry. :) didn't notice it. My main research area is not Electronic simulation since I'm a Computer science undergrad so I have to give priority to Software Engineering aspects.

Comment: I haven't seen an API for SPICE, but you might want to check out the source of ngspice and tclspice, or talk to their developers.

Answer (score 3):

ummm spice does not really need an api ..... spice simulation file looks something like this

```
LPFILTER.CIR - SIMPLE RC LOW-PASS FILTER
*
VS  1   0   AC  1   SIN(0VOFF 1VPEAK   2KHZ)
*
R1  1   2   1K
C1  2   0   0.032UF
*
* ANALYSIS
.AC     DEC     5 10 10MEG
.TRAN   5US  500US
*
* VIEW RESULTS
.PRINT  AC  VM(2) VP(2)
.PRINT  TRAN    V(1) V(2)
*
.PROBE
.END
```

everything is driven by text files in the background and these files are passed to a pspice exe that normally does the rest.  The spice engine itself is available with a BSD license so you can tweak it yourself.

Most commercial offerings offer schematic entry, parts libraries and output plotting options.

You can do away with this be passing in a netlist file with the simulation details to an spice engine and get back a text file of results.

So no real api just a command line driven app.  Of course you can get the source code and compile it into you own application.

check out wikipedia for more details.

Comment: thanks for the reply. You mean that for instance, I can get  potential difference automatically calculated between a particular device, after giving circuit setup structure details into the spice?

Comment: yes you can - but garbage in garbage out - you have to know the electronics circuits (or math representation) you are trying to calculate to write the netlist, and include the correct analysis - in this case dc bias, it should spit out the answer for you

Comment: How can I get simulation results after writing the input text file? would you be interested in a related freelance project for android?